# URL-encode single quote character?

Tags: delphi, urlencode, delphi-xe8

For URL-Encoding/Decoding, it has been suggested to use `TNetEncoding` from Delphi XE7 upwards.

So in Delphi XE8 i use this code for example:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding;
...
edtEncodedURL.Text := TNetEncoding.URL.Encode('SetFont(''Arial'',15)');
```

which gives the following result:

> SetFont('Arial'%2C15)

However, this does not encode the single quote characters, as you can see from the example above.

Moreover, at [W3Schools.com HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp), in the "Try It Yourself" section, the string `SetFont('Arial',15)` is URL-encoded to:

> SetFont%28%27Arial%27%2C15%29

So is there a way to URL-encode also the single quote characters in Delphi XE8?

Comment: [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) explicitly allows single quote characters to remain unencoded in URL, and since this spec is what the Delphi conversion unit appears to be based on, I guess the answer is No.

Comment: `REST.Utils.URIEncode` seems to do the work: It gets `SetFont%28%27Arial%27%2C15%29` from `SetFont('Arial',15)`.

Comment: On the other way, `TNetEncoding.URL.Decode` does the job with all encoded characters: It CORRECTLY decodes `SetFont%28%27Arial%27%2C15%29` back to `SetFont('Arial',15)`.

Comment: So there seems to be a logical inconsistency between `TNetEncoding.URL.Encode` and `TNetEncoding.URL.Decode`?

Comment: @user1580348: Not really. ANY character is allowed to be encoded, so `Decode()` has to account for that. But only certain character are REQUIRED to be encoded, and `Encode()` accounts for that (mostly - it doesn't take context into account, as some characters are required to be encoded in particular portions of the URL, but may be left unencoded in other portions).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: RFC 1738 is obsolete, look at [RFC 3986 ](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work for the purpose asked in the question:

```
uses
  System.NetEncoding,
  REST.Utils;

procedure TForm1.btnURLEncodeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtEncodedURL.Text := REST.Utils.URIEncode(edtOriginalURL.Text);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnURLDecodeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  edtDecodedURL.Text := TNetEncoding.URL.Decode(edtEncodedURL.Text);
end;
```

[image]